# Experimenting with babeljs+amd getting undefined for module

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd, babeljs

I'm experimenting with babel.js alongside with RequireJS. Require is given, I can't drop it sadly :(
I found in the babeljs docs that there's a `--modules amd` cli flag which transpiles ES6 code to AMD defines. So far so good. I made a quick example "application" to test it out. Here's the structure:

```
.
|-- build.sh
|-- index.html
|-- js
|   |-- assets
|   |   |-- asseta.es6
|   |   |-- asseta.js
|   |   |-- bootstrap.es6
|   |   `-- bootstrap.js
|   `-- main.js
`-- node_modules
```

#### index.html

```
<body>
    <p>Hello world! This is HTML5 Boilerplate.</p>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/requirejs/require.js" data-main="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

#### main.js

```
(function() {
  require.config({
    baseUrl: "js/assets"
  });
  require(["bootstrap"], function(bootstrap) {
    bootstrap.ready(function(sum) {
      console.log(sum(1,2,3));
    });
  });
}());
```

#### bootstrap.es6

```
import asseta from 'asseta';

console.log(asseta); // undefined :((

export function ready(cb) {
  cb(asseta.sum);
}
```

#### asseta.es6

```
export function sum(...nums) {
  return nums.reduce(((acc, num) => acc += num), 0);
}
```

My problem with the application is that `main.js` loads `bootstrap` properly, if I log it out I got an existing object with the ready function in it -> OK
But the `bootstrap` module **can't** load the `asseta` module properly. I get undefined for that :(

What am I missing?

#### Additional info

The `build.sh` script only transpiles .es6 files to ES5 .js

```
#!/bin/sh

babel --modules amd js/assets/bootstrap.es6 -o js/assets/bootstrap.js
babel --modules amd js/assets/asseta.es6 -o js/assets/asseta.js
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a user error. I missed a `default` keyword in `asseta.es6` like

```
export default function sum(...nums) {
  return nums.reduce(((acc, num) => acc += num), 0);
}
```

Or the other approach to fix it would be to omit the `default` keyword from `asseta` but refactor `bootstrap` as

```
import { sum } from 'asseta';
```